# Inject a React component as a prop when it has mandatory props in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a `React` `TreeView` component with `Typescript`. I would like the flexibility to be able to inject a template `TreeNode` component that renders each node.

How can I type my `TreeNode`'s props so I can inject `TreeNode` into `TreeView` as a prop without `typescript` complaining that I'm not providing my `TreeNode`s props yet, even though they will be down the road when `TreeView` builds the hierarchy and feeds each `TreeNode` with appropriate `props`.

I tried to strip down my code to the minimum:

```
interface TreeNodeProps {
    id: string
    title: string
}

const TreeNode: React.SFC<TreeNodeProps > = (props) => {
  return (
    <div key={props.id}>
        <div>{props.title}</div>
        <div>{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

const TreeView: React.SFC<{treeData: any, TreeNode: JSX.Element}> = (props) => {
  // here's the logic where each TreeNode's props will be fed with graph's props.
    const buildTreeRecursively = (treeData) =>
        treeData.map((node) => {                
            if (node.children.length > 0) {
                return (
                    <TreeNode id={node.id} title={node.title}>
                        {buildTreeRecursively(node.children)}
                    </TreeNode>
                )
            }
            return <TreeNode id={node.id} title={node.title} />
        })

  return (
        <div className={styles.treeView}>
            {buildTreeRecursively(props.treeData)}
        </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
const buildTreeRecursively = (treeData: React.PropsWithChildren<TreeNodeProps>[]) =>
    treeData.map((node) => {
        if (node.children) {
            return (
                <TreeNode id={node.id} title={node.title}>
                    {buildTreeRecursively(node.children as React.PropsWithChildren<TreeNodeProps>[])}
                </TreeNode>
            )
        }
        return <TreeNode id={node.id} title={node.title} />
    })
```

If I leave the `if (node.children.length > 0)`, I get the compile error

> Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.

and since the type of `node.children` is a superset of `React.PropsWithChildren<TreeNodeProps>[]`, we have to cast it since we know we're only using that subset of the type.

I got the idea for `treeData`'s type by looking at the type hint for `props` from

```
const TreeNode: React.SFC<TreeNodeProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div key={props.id}>
        <div>{props.title}</div>
        <div>{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

which was `React.PropsWithChildren<TreeNodeProps>`.